# undefined: grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7 grpc.ServiceRegistrar

Tags: docker, go, protocol-buffers

Inside docker, it seems that I cannot compile my gRPC micro-service due to this error:

```
Step 4/9 : RUN make build
 ---> Running in ceb6e4d0e19b
protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4
protoc --proto_path=pkg/proto/notify/ --go_out=pkg/proto/notify/ --go-grpc_out=pkg/proto/notify/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative notify.proto

plugin versions reported in *.pb.go files:
./pkg/proto/notify/notify.pb.go://  protoc-gen-go v1.25.0-devel
./pkg/proto/notify/notify.pb.go://  protoc        v3.12.4

go build -o notify-service *.go
go: downloading github.com/lib/pq v1.7.0
go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.27.0
go: downloading github.com/jinzhu/gorm v1.9.14
go: downloading github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.33.7
go: downloading github.com/go-kit/kit v0.10.0
go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.25.0
go: downloading github.com/go-co-op/gocron v0.2.1
go: downloading github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.6.0
go: downloading github.com/golang/protobuf v1.4.2
go: downloading github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2 v2.1.0
go: downloading github.com/jhillyerd/enmime v0.8.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20200523222454-059865788121
go: downloading github.com/jaytaylor/html2text v0.0.0-20190408195923-01ec452cbe43
go: downloading github.com/vanng822/go-premailer v0.0.0-20191214114701-be27abe028fe
go: downloading github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.9
go: downloading github.com/russross/blackfriday/v2 v2.0.1
go: downloading github.com/jinzhu/inflection v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/sprig v2.16.0+incompatible
go: downloading golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20200520182314-0ba52f642ac2
go: downloading github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery v1.5.1
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.3.2
go: downloading github.com/vanng822/css v0.0.0-20190504095207-a21e860bcd04
go: downloading github.com/shurcooL/sanitized_anchor_name v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/aokoli/goutils v1.0.1
go: downloading google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20200526211855-cb27e3aa2013
go: downloading gopkg.in/gormigrate.v1 v1.6.0
go: downloading github.com/gorilla/css v1.0.0
go: downloading github.com/ssor/bom v0.0.0-20170718123548-6386211fdfcf
go: downloading github.com/andybalholm/cascadia v1.1.0
go: downloading github.com/gogs/chardet v0.0.0-20150115103509-2404f7772561
go: downloading golang.org/x/crypto v0.0.0-20200510223506-06a226fb4e37
go: downloading github.com/olekukonko/tablewriter v0.0.1
go: downloading github.com/cention-sany/utf7 v0.0.0-20170124080048-26cad61bd60a
go: downloading github.com/huandu/xstrings v1.2.0
go: downloading github.com/Masterminds/semver v1.4.2
go: downloading github.com/google/uuid v1.1.1
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-runewidth v0.0.4
go: downloading github.com/go-logfmt/logfmt v0.5.0
go: downloading github.com/jmespath/go-jmespath v0.3.0
# gitlab.com/kuecr/fero/backend/notify/pkg/proto/notify
pkg/proto/notify/notify_grpc.pb.go:14:11: undefined: grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion7
pkg/proto/notify/notify_grpc.pb.go:71:30: undefined: grpc.ServiceRegistrar
make: *** [Makefile:14: build] Error 2
ERROR: Service 'notify' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c make build' returned a non-zero code: 2
make: *** [Makefile:64: build/notify] Error 1
```

However, outside of Docker the thing is run and compile with success.

This is my base Docker image:

```
RG go_version

FROM golang:${go_version}-buster

ARG pb_version

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential curl git wget unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v${pb_version}/protobuf-cpp-${pb_version}.zip && \
        unzip protobuf-cpp-${pb_version}.zip && \
        cd protobuf-${pb_version} && \
        ./configure  && \
        make  && \
        make check  && \
        make install  && \
        ldconfig && \
        cd ../ && \
        rm -rf protobuf-*

RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon && \
        go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go && \
        go get github.com/grpc/grpc-go/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc && \
        go install github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go && \
        go install github.com/grpc/grpc-go/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc
```

This is the Docker image where the compilation is done:

```
FROM registry.gitlab.com/kuecr/devops/go-protobuf-base:1.14 as base

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN make build

FROM base as testing

ENTRYPOINT ["make", "test"]

FROM base as production

RUN make build

ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon -log-prefix=false -build="go build -o notify-service" -command="./notify-service"
```

My docker and docker-compose and protoc versions:

```
✖ docker --version && docker-compose --version
Docker version 19.03.12-ce, build 48a66213fe
docker-compose version 1.26.2, build unknown
➜ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4
```

This is what happens when I ran `make build` on my machine:

```
➜ make build
protoc --version
libprotoc 3.12.4
protoc --proto_path=pkg/proto/notify/ --go_out=pkg/proto/notify/ --go-grpc_out=pkg/proto/notify/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative notify.proto

plugin versions reported in *.pb.go files:
./pkg/proto/notify/notify.pb.go://  protoc-gen-go v1.25.0
./pkg/proto/notify/notify.pb.go://  protoc        v3.12.4

go build -o notify-service *.go
```

I'm using Golang 1.15 while the Docker image use 1.14.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gist of this error is that the version of binary used to generate the code isn't compatible with the current version of code. A quick and easy solution would be to try updating the `protoc-gen-go` compiler and the gRPC library to the latest version.

go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go

then regen the proto

[heres](https://www.reddit.com/r/grpc/comments/ih5qn5/undefined_grpcsupportpackageisversion7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) a link to a reddit thread that discusses the issue

Answer (score 24):

Already they have provided this solution in their documentation [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go#compiling-error-undefined-grpcsupportpackageisversion). I had the same issue and here is my solution:

```
go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}
go get -u google.golang.org/grpc
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:. *.proto
```

[Here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go#if-you-are-not-using-go-modules) is the explanation if you are not using *Go modules*:

Answer (score 5):

**`grpc.SupportPackageIsVersion`** is used to track the version of the protobuf generated code and is different from the grpc release version.

In short, Your generated GRPC code structure is newer than your `google.golang.org/grpc` package. So you must update your `go grpc` package to the new one.

`SupportPackageIsVersion7` support after `1.32.0` versions. and they support old versions with **go version >= 1.12**

to update it you should

- first, remove the current one, to find where it stored, you can use the `echo $PATH`  command to find out where this file is. then remove it.
- second, install the new one, for installing it you can run this command.

  `go install google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc`

  **Note** If you have any problem to get it, use this command instead,

  `go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go`

after the update, you must edit your `go.mod` file.

change this line:

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.21.1
```

to

```
google.golang.org/grpc v1.32.0// or newer
```

**Note:** You can find last releases from this [URL](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/releases)

You can find versions supports of the package at the end of `rpc_util.go` in constants.

something like this:

```
const (
    SupportPackageIsVersion3 = true
    SupportPackageIsVersion4 = true
    SupportPackageIsVersion5 = true
    SupportPackageIsVersion6 = true
    SupportPackageIsVersion7 = true
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by specifying grpc-go version to `v1.33.0-dev`, but this version is not included in ver `v1.31.1`.

Comment: you mean setting a version for `github.com/grpc/grpc-go/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc`?

Comment: nope, set version for `google.golang.org/grpc`, like this: `google.golang.org/grpc v1.33.0-dev` (one line in go.mod)

Comment: is it fine using version which is not official ?

Comment: @MeiLie It is a *dev* version but not *not official*. Also I have just checked the latest (grpc-go-1.34.0)[https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/releases/tag/v1.34.0] version and found the `SupportPackageIsVersion7` has been added.

Answer (score 3):

Even with `go get -u` my version for some reason didn't get updated to the last one. I had to update `google.golang.org/grpc v1.27.0` to `google.golang.org/grpc v1.34.0` (latest version attow) in my go.mod manually. Then it worked.

Comment: work with latest version

Answer (score 1):

Complementary to @Jay Lane answer, I want to share the Dockerfile configuration I put together:

```
ARG go_version

FROM golang:${go_version}-buster

ARG pb_version
ARG grpc_version
ARG gen_version
ARG compile_daemon_version
ARG dlv_version

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential curl git wget unzip && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v${pb_version}/protobuf-cpp-${pb_version}.zip && \
        unzip protobuf-cpp-${pb_version}.zip && \
        cd protobuf-${pb_version} && \
        ./configure  && \
        make  && \
        make check  && \
        make install  && \
        ldconfig && \
        cd ../ && \
        rm -rf protobuf-*

WORKDIR /tmp

RUN GO111MODULE=on go get google.golang.org/protobuf/cmd/protoc-gen-go@v${gen_version} && \
        GO111MODULE=on go get google.golang.org/grpc@v${grpc_version} && \
        GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon@v${compile_daemon_version} && \
        GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@v${dlv_version}


RUN git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go.git && \
        cd grpc-go/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc && \
        git checkout v${grpc_version} && go install . && \
        cd /tmp && rm -rf grpc-go

WORKDIR /go
```

and I also updated `google.golang.org/grpc` to `v1.31.1`.

EDIT:

This is the Makefile I use to help me build this image, is included for the sake of completeness:

```
GO_VERSION=1.14
PROTOBUF_VERSION=3.12.4
GEN_VERSION=1.25.0
GRPC_VERSION=1.31.1
COMPILE_DAEMON_VERSION=1.2.1
DLV_VERSION=1.5.0

push: build
    docker push registry.gitlab.com/kuecr/devops/go-protobuf-base:$(GO_VERSION)

build:
    docker build \
        --build-arg pb_version=$(PROTOBUF_VERSION) \
        --build-arg go_version=$(GO_VERSION) \
        --build-arg gen_version=$(GEN_VERSION) \
        --build-arg grpc_version=$(GRPC_VERSION) \
        --build-arg compile_daemon_version=$(COMPILE_DAEMON_VERSION) \
        --build-arg dlv_version=$(DLV_VERSION) \
    -t registry.gitlab.com/kuecr/devops/go-protobuf-base:$(GO_VERSION) .

history:
    docker image history registry.gitlab.com/kuecr/devops/go-protobuf-base:$(GO_VERSION)

sh:
    docker run --rm --interactive --tty --entrypoint /bin/sh registry.gitlab.com/kuecr/devops/go-protobuf-base:$(GO_VERSION)
```